# Select rows from a table where all values of an array exist

Tags: mysql

I have this query that retreives a list of id's + NAME:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM #__table1 ";

$sql .= " WHERE (";
foreach($explode_tags as $k=>$explode_tag) {
  $sql .= "name = ".$db->Quote(trim($explode_tag));
  if(($k+1) != count($explode_tags))
  $sql .= " OR ";
}
$sql .= ")";        

$db->setQuery($sql);
$results = $db->loadResultArray();
```

The result is an array like this:

```
keywordID    |    NAME
1                 cat
2                 dog
3                 horse
```

Now I have this table2:

```
id   |    ItemID    |    keywordID
1            4              1
2            4              2
3            4              3
4            6              1
5            6              2
6            7              1
```

I want to find from table2 all ItemID's that have all keywordID's found in table1. 
In the example above I want to return only itemID 4 that has all keywords (all 3 of them).

I am running this query but I am not getting results:

```
...
$query .= " AND i.id IN (SELECT itemID FROM #__table2 WHERE (";
foreach($results as $k=>$result) {
$query .= "keywordID = ".(int)$result;
if(($k+1) != count($results))
$query .= " AND ";
}
$query .= "))";
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by what the end result is you are trying to achieve. Can you give an example of the table you are looking to produce from your query?

Comment: I want to find from table2 all ItemID's that have all keywordID's found in table1. In the example above I want to return only itemID=4 that has all keywords (all 3 of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I miss read your question. I've done simple test using this data:

```
id  itemId  keywordId
1   4       1
5   4       2
6   4       3
7   5       2
8   5       3
9   6       1
10  6       2
11  6       3
12  7       3
13  9       3
14  9       2
15  9       1
```

and using this query:

```
SELECT itemId, GROUP_CONCAT( keywordId ORDER BY keywordId ) AS crpcnct, COUNT( itemId ) 
FROM  `temporary_table_123` 
GROUP BY 1 
HAVING crpcnct =  '1,2,3'
```

I can get the value that you wanted:

```
itemId  crpcnct  count(itemId)
4       1,2,3    3
6       1,2,3    3
9       1,2,3    3
```

To achieve this, all you have to do is build the keywordID you want to use:

```
$keywordIds[] = $results['keywordId'];
```

and then sort accending

```
sort($keywordIds);
```

the last step is, supply this array into query:

```
SELECT itemId, GROUP_CONCAT( keywordId ORDER BY keywordId ) AS crpcnct, COUNT( itemId ) 
FROM  `temporary_table_123` 
GROUP BY 1 
HAVING crpcnct =  '" . implode(",", $keywordIds) . "'
```

There you have it.

Comment: If I change "AND" to "OR" in 2nd query I get all ItemID's that have any of the keywords while I need to return only ItemID's that contain all keywords found in 1st query.

Comment: @silent, which table is the "temporary_table_123" ?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ItemID FROM table2 WHERE keywordID IN (SELECT keywordID FROM table1)`

This might work. I'll have to create local copies of your tables to see for sure, though.

Comment: Wait, this won't accomplish what you want. It will only tell you if the keywordID is valid. I'll update in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array_names = array();
foreach($explode_tags as $k=>$explode_tag){
    $array_names[] = 'name = ' . $db->Quote(trim($explode_tag));
}

$sql = "SELECT ItemID FROM table_2 WHERE keywordID IN (SELECT keywordID FROM table_1 WHERE " . implode(' OR ', $array_names) .")";
$db->setQuery($sql);
$results = $db->loadResultArray();
```